# Can I check in my cs project properties on tfs?

Tags: c#, tfs, properties, visual-studio-2017, csproj

I have two problems I am trying to keep my configurations so every member of my team can have this configuration on their product.In the image bellow when I change the number 1 from debug to any other thing it clears my properties 2 and 3. I am trying to check in this properties so all the team can use that without reproducing it in every machine.

Any idea how to check in this properties in TFS? And how to stop it from clear my properties?

[image: My properties]

Comment: Did you configure all build profiles and save? Debug, Release, ... with the information that you needed in the file you have an image of before changing your build profile in the IDE??

Comment: Your screenshot is unreadable

Comment: 1- change debug to release 
2- properties debug start external program
3- comand line arguments
yes I have all configured on release and debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I check in my cs project properties on tfs?

I am afraid you could not check the default configuration setting and debugging properties in TFS.

That because those properties are artefacts, not source files, and have no place being in the source control system. You just think the One simple question: Do you need them to build your code? If not, you could not add them to source control.

Things like your editor color preferences or keybindings are not part of the build system. Compiler flags and so on are.

Besides, those properties are based on the Visual Studio instead of source file, TFS could not store the hardware setting in the source control.

**Update:**

> Thanks for your answer but I need this configurations to build my product. Is any way to create a properties file to do that?

If you insist on doing this, I can provide you with a solution. Those properties info are stored in the `.user` file, which located at the same folder of project file.

Then you could move the this file from the `.gitignore` or `.tfignore`.

Hope this helps.